# PHP Security with databases

Tags: php, mysql, security

Do I have to worry about any security concerns with my MySQL connections. In my project I have a PHP file with all of my connection information and statements that need run in various functions that I use a require once or ajax statement to get data from.

Like with

```
<?php
     require_once '../includes/game_query.php';
     game_page_query(1);
 ?>
```

Which calls into the file runs a query and echos some generated html onto the page.

Is there anyway that that can be exploited/attacked since the connection info that does the select is visible in the PHP file?

Comment: don't put sensitive files inside your document root, then... if php ever gets disabled/breaks on your server, those files are likely to get served up as plain text and you'd be exposing all of your php code to the world. if the file's not in the document root, it won't be reachable by end-users at all.

Comment: @MarcB so then my solution to that particular security issue would be to move my documents with the SQL information outside of the htdocs folder on the server?

Comment: that's up to you. php generally couldn't care less where the files are. it works at the filesystem level and is almost entirely NOT constrained by apache's own security system.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you are using [prepared SQL statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or at the very least escape the database parameters.

If you're worried about PHP details being exposed, say if your PHP interpreter turns off and everything becomes visible via the webserver (as someone mentioned in the comments to your question); you have two options. The first one is to move the file containing sensitive information a level above the directory where web server files are included then adding an extra ../ to your require. The other option is to limit access to the file directly via .htaccess.

If you don't want to allow execution of your PHP files directly but also if you want to not have to do what I described in the previous paragraph what you can do is:

Firstly place this above your require in a PHP script where you include the file:

```
define('includeAllow', true);
```

Then add this to the file itself below the opening PHP tag:

```
if (!defined('includeAllow')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}
```

Note that if PHP was disabled on the server, the connection info could still be exposed by the server.

I should clarify, while the PHP interpreter is turned on, someone cannot view the source of the PHP file unless they have access to the files on the server (i.e. over SSH/FTP), in my experience I have never seen the PHP interpreter turned off accidentally or PHP accidentally uninstalled from the server.

[XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) and [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks are more frequent than this type of exploit. These are the types of exploit you need to protect yourself against.